# Encrypting constant strings(e.g. Password) in compiled executable

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, security

I've created a application which requires a database to display information. It is highly imperative that no one without the password can access the database.

But when I went through my executable, I found that the database password was in plain text.

Here's my code:

```
char pass[20]="MyPassword";
ui->setupUi(this);
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL3");
db.setConnectOptions();
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("DB");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword(pass);
```

Here is what I found in the .exe binary:

```
p< S       |   t¼  t¬    ?   @   €   0   @  €  À 0 @   €  MyPassword  QMYSQL3 localhost   DB
```

This is kind of worrying. Is there a workaround so that my password also gets encrypted?

Comment: At some point you're going to have to decrypt the password, so either way a determined person could access your database. If you want a secure database then you should consider putting it on a server, and have users login. But, of course, this won't help if you hardcode that password into the application anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing a password in an application is in general a very bad idea.
As user1520427 indicated, even if you encrypt your password, somewhere in your code you have to decrypt it. That means, that it appears somewhere in memory.
A determined hacker can fetch this.
By encrypting it, you make the life of the hacker a little bit more difficult.
So, you should know that it is **never** safe to store a password in an application if it is **highly imperative** that no one can access your database. No encryption can prevent this.
You can make the life of a hacker a little bit more difficult be applying some techniques:

1. Hash the password
   This makes it only less readable in the resulting `.exe`, but rest assured that a hacker has a trained eye and will directly recognise a hash.
2. Split the password in several pieces
   This results in the password being distributed in the .exe

   ```
   QString part1 = "ace12"
   ... somewhere else 
   QString part2 = "32ef0"
   ... and so on
   ... somewhere else
   QString password = part1 + part2
   ```

You could even attach some garbage to this parts, like

```
    QString part1 = "ace12acaae2b1ccc0e969709665bc62f"  
    QString part2 = "32ef031ec4b7ad76b6270bd8c8f971d0"
    ...
    QString password = part1.leftRef(5) + part2.leftRef(5) + ...
```

3. Do not login as `root`
Whenever a hacker can crack the password, he has immediate root access to the database.
 4. Use an SSL connection to the database server.
Even with all the trickery above, a simple network sniffer can reveal the password. So be sure to protect the connection as well.

These are layman's methods, and are guaranteed to be cracked by a determined hacker.

If you really really want to be safe, then you need to use an SSO solution (see https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/security.html). That is the only way to do this correctly.